# Fix the solution of "Binary period"

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

I found this task and completely stuck with its solution.

A non-empty zero-indexed string S consisting of Q characters is given. The period of this string is the smallest positive integer P such that:

P ≤ Q / 2 and S[K] = S[K+P] for 0 ≤ K < Q − P.

For example, 7 is the period of “abracadabracadabra”. A positive integer M is the binary period of a positive integer N if M is the period of the binary representation of N.

For example, 1651 has the binary representation of "110011100111". Hence, its binary period is 5. On the other hand, 102 does not have a binary period, because its binary representation is “1100110” and it does not have a period.

Consider above scenarios & write a function in Python which will accept an integer N as the parameter. Given a positive integer N, the function returns the binary period of N or −1 if N does not have a binary period.

The attached code is still incorrect on some inputs (9, 11, 13, 17 etc). The goal is to find and fix the bugs in the implementation. You can modify at most **2** line.

```
def binary_period(n):
    d = [0] * 30
    l = 0
    while n > 0:
        d[l] = n % 2
        n //= 2
        l += 1
    for p in range(1, 1 + l):
        ok = True
        for i in range(l - p):
            if d[i] != d[i + p]:
                ok = False
                break
        if ok:
            return p
    return -1
```

Comment: can you provide sample test cases where it fails ?

Comment: @venkatakrishnan for example 9 is "1001". but the function returns 3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was given this piece of code in an interview.

The aim of the exercice is to see where lies the bug.

As an input of the function, you will type the integer to see the binary period of it. As an example `solution(4)` will give you a binary number of `0011`.

However, the question is the following: What is the bug?

The bug in this occasion is not some crash and burn code, rather a behavior that should happen and in the code, do not happen.

It is known as a [logical error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_error) in the code. Logical error is the error when code do not break but doesn't fullfill the requirements.

Using a brute force on the code will not help as there are a billion possibilities.

However if you run the code, let's say from `solutions(1)` to `solutions(100)`, you will see that the code runs without any glitch. Yet if you are looking at the code, it should return `-1` if there are errors.

The code is not givin any `-1` even if you run solutions to a with bigger number like 10000.

The bug here lies in the -1 that is not being triggered.

So let's go step by step on the code.

Could it be the `while` part?

```
while n > 0:
    d[l] = n % 2
    n //= 2
    l += 1
```

If you look at the code, it is doing what it should be doing, changing the number given to a binary number, even if it is doing from a backward position. Instead of having `1011`, you have `1101` but it does the job.

The issue lies rather in that part

```
for p in range(1, 1 + l):
        ok = True
        for i in range(l - p):
            if d[i] != d[i + p]:
                ok = False
                break
        if ok:
            return p
return -1
```

It is not returning `-1`.

if you put some print on some part of the code like this, this would give you this

```
for p in range(1, 1 + l):
    ok = True
    for i in range(l - p):
        print('l, which works as an incrementor is substracted to p of the first loop',p,l-p)
        if d[i] != d[i + p]:
            ok = False
            break
    if ok:
        return p
return -1
```

If you run the whole script, actually, you can see that it is never ending even if `d[i]` is not equal anymore to `d[i+p]`.

But why?

The reason is because l, the incrementor was built on an integer division. Because of that, you need to do a `1+l//2`.

Which gives you the following

```
def solution(n):
    d = [0] * 30
    l = 0
    while n > 0:
        d[l] = n % 2
        n //= 2
        l += 1
    for p in range(1, 1 + l//2): #here you put l//2
        ok = True
        print('p est ',p)
        for i in range(l - p):
            if d[i] != d[i + p]:
                ok = False
                break
        if ok:
            return
```

Now if you run the code with `solutions(5)` for example, the bug should be fixed and you should have `-1`.

---

Addendum:

This test is a difficult one with a not easy algorithm to deal with in very short time, with variables that does not make any sense.

First step would be to ask the following questions:

- What is the input of the algorithm? In this case, it is an integer.
- What is the expected output? In this case, a `-1`
- Is it a logical error or a crash and burn kind of error? In this case, it is a logical error.

These step-by-step ([heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic)) will set you on the right direction to debug a problem.

Comment: Hey! thanks for your answer on this coding challange and sorry for my belated question, but I was wondering why this line `d = [0] * 30` is ok? if I try with 2^32-1 the code breaks... right?

Comment: @hdlopez `d = [0] * 30` is making a list of 30 zeros. `2 power 32 minus 1` is like using brute force. Idk but likely, it will work.

Answer (score 7):

Following up Andy's solution and checking @hdlopez comment, there is a border case when passing int.MaxVal=2147483647
and if you do not increase the array size to 31 (instead of 30). The function throws an index out of range, so two places need to be modified:

1-   `int[] d = new int[31];  //changed 30 to 31 (unsigned integer)`

2-  `for (p = 1; p < 1 + l / 2; ++p)  //added division to l per statement, P ≤ Q / 2`

Comment: yep! that's was exactly my fix to the problem. Thanks @jvmcollaborator